# Task library for C?

Tags: c, linux, task-parallel-library

Is there a task library for C? I'm talking about the parallel task library as it exists in C#, or Java. In other words, I need a layer of abstraction over `pthread` for Linux. Thanks.

Comment: Consider Intel Threading Building Blocks, if C++ is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Give a look at [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/).
In particular, you might be interested in the [Task](https://iwomp.zih.tu-dresden.de/downloads/omp30-tasks.pdf) feature of OpenMP 3.0.

I suggest you, however, to try to see if your problem can be solved using other, "basic" constructs, such as parallel for, since they are simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most widely-used parallel programming primitives aside from the Win32 ones are those provided by [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).

They are quite low-level but include everything you need to write an efficient blocking queue and so create a thread pool of workers that carry out a queue of asynchronous tasks.

There is also a [Win32 implementation](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) so you can use the same codebase on Windows as well as POSIX systems.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I learned something new now. Is there some sort of tutorial to build these worker tasks? I think the problem is I don't know how to schedule a task onto a OS thread.

Comment: The first link above is to a tutorial. It includes an example of using condition variables which is the basic building block on which you build a blocking queue, which then becomes the basic building block for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Many concepts in **TPL** (Task, Work-Stealing Scheduler,...) are inspired by a very successful project named [Cilk](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/) at MIT. Their advanced framework (**Cilk Plus**) was acquired by Intel and integrated to Intel Parallel Building Block. You still can use **Cilk** as an [open source project](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/intro.html) without some advanced features. The good news is [Intel is releasing Cilk Plus as open source in GCC](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-cilk-plus/).

You should try out **Cilk** as it adds another layer of abstraction to C, which makes it easy to express parallel algorithms but it is close enough to C to ensure good performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been meaning to checking out [libdispatch](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/). Yeah it's built for OS X and blocks, but they have function interfaces as well. Haven't really had time to look at it yet though so not sure if it fills all your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is an academia project called [Wool](http://www.sics.se/~kff/wool/) that implements work stealing scheduler in C (with significant help of C preprocessor AFAIK). Might be worth looking at, though it does not seem actively developed.